# Reorganise data from Rows to Column in SQL

Tags: sql

I am on uni project and stuck with this. I have some data below and I want to change and look like in the 2nd table. Is this possible to do in SQL and can it be a dynamic one? any suggestions from anyone?

Sample data:

```
+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------------------------+
|  dbk   | item  |   dpi    |  dvb   |           name            |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------------------------+
| 816408 | Air   |  9882067 | 383311 | Virgin Australia          |
| 816432 | Other |  7205311 | 376023 | House of Travel Ltd       |
| 816432 | Other |  7205312 | 376023 | House of Travel Ltd       |
| 816553 | Hotel | 10205063 | 387077 | Mantra On Salt Beach      |
| 816553 | Ins   | 10205064 | 377326 | Allianz Global Assistance |
| 816553 | Ins   | 10205065 | 377326 | Allianz Global Assistance |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205066 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205067 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205068 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Fee   | 10205069 |      0 | Unknown                   |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205070 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205071 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205072 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Ins   | 10205073 | 377326 | Allianz Global Assistance |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205074 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205075 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Air   | 10205076 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816553 | Ins   | 10205077 | 377326 | Allianz Global Assistance |
| 816553 | Ins   | 10205078 | 377326 | Allianz Global Assistance |
| 816610 | Air   |  9986532 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816610 | Other |  9986533 | 375964 | HOT Dunedin Ltd           |
| 816610 | Air   |  9986534 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816649 | Other | 10211542 | 383181 | Conxion                   |
| 816649 | Other | 10211543 | 383181 | Conxion                   |
| 816649 | Other | 10211544 | 383181 | Conxion                   |
| 816649 | Other | 10211545 | 383181 | Conxion                   |
| 816649 | Fee   | 10211546 |      0 | Unknown                   |
| 816649 | Air   | 10211547 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816649 | Air   | 10211548 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
| 816649 | Hotel | 10211549 | 384400 | Mantra Sun City           |
| 816743 | Air   |  7204575 | 382920 | Qantas Airways            |
| 816743 | Air   |  7204576 | 382920 | Qantas Airways            |
| 816779 | Fee   |  7204884 |      0 | Unknown                   |
| 816866 | Air   |  9892676 | 375704 | Air New Zealand           |
+--------+-------+----------+--------+---------------------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+--------+------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  dbk   |       Air        |   Fee   |        Hotel         |            Ins            |        Other        |
+--------+------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
| 816408 | Virgin Australia |         |                      |                           |                     |
| 816432 |                  |         |                      |                           | House of Travel Ltd |
| 816553 | Air New Zealand  | Unknown | Mantra On Salt Beach | Allianz Global Assistance |                     |
| 816610 | Air New Zealand  |         |                      |                           | HOT Dunedin Ltd     |
| 816649 | Air New Zealand  | Unknown | Mantra Sun City      |                           | Conxion             |
| 816743 | Qantas Airways   |         |                      |                           |                     |
| 816779 |                  | Unknown |                      |                           |                     |
| 816866 | Air New Zealand  |         |                      |                           |                     |
+--------+------------------+---------+----------------------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Please don't post links to offsite resources for information about your question.  Post all relevant information directly into your question.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 0):

this will do (assuming SQL Server):

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') is not null
    drop table #tmp;

create table #tmp
(
    tmp_sid int not null identity(1,1),
    dbk varchar(80),
    item varchar(80),
    dpi varchar(80),
    dvb varchar(80),
    name varchar(80)
);

insert into #tmp values('816408','Air','9882067','383311','Virgin Australia');
insert into #tmp values('816432','Other','7205311','376023','House of Travel Ltd');
insert into #tmp values('816432','Other','7205312','376023','House of Travel Ltd');
insert into #tmp values('816432','Other','7205312','376023','House of Travel Ltd');
insert into #tmp values('816553','Hotel','10205063','387077','Mantra On Salt Beach');
insert into #tmp values('816553','Ins','10205064','377326','Allianz Global Assistance');
insert into #tmp values('816553','Ins','10205065','377326','Allianz Global Assistance');
insert into #tmp values('816553','Fee','10205069','0','Unknown');

declare @q varchar(max);

select
    @q = coalesce(@q + ',', '') + QUOTENAME(item)
from
    #tmp
group by 
    item;

set @q = 'select dbk,' + @q + 'from #tmp pivot (max(item) for item in (' + @q + ')) U'

exec (@q);
```

Comment: Thanks. But any suggestion for a dynamic one?

Comment: Please provide more input, why dynamic? what data could you run into?

Comment: I just gave a fixed number of Item names.. I have multiple Items, may be around 50 and would increase...

Comment: just build the query in a string variable and concatenate the distinct items and put them in both columns and pivot like in the example above and then run it with exec(@query);